# Accessing file system through ioctl function

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel, ioctl

Recently, I developed a simple file system kernel module.
So, I needed to assign my own ioctl function (`.unlocked_ioctl`) to the `file_operation` structure to implement specific commands to my file system module. The Ext4 file system has its own ioctl function, for example.

Then, I created a file using the `dd` command and mounted it:

```
# mount -t myfs -o loop simple_file /mnt/
```

Everything works fine, but how can I access this file system using ioctl with a user space program?

I tryed to do `ioctl(fd, MY_COMMAND_1, &my_struct_t);` (where `fd` is the file descriptor of the dev file `/dev/loop[0..7]`), but it returns me `Invalid argument`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open `/dev/loop0`, you're accessing a loop device, and therefore you're talking to the loop driver.

The ioctl handler that you've registered for your filesystem applies to files opened on a mounted filesystem.

```
fd = open("/mnt/something", O_RDWR);
ioctl(fd, MY_COMMAND_1, &my_struct_t);
```

Comment: Thanks @Gilles. I did it, but it returned me `Inappropriate ioctl for device`. So, I noticed I was using `file_operations` only for directories and I changed to `fd = open("/mnt/something/", O_RDWR);` and the code worked. =)